# how to position a child (the container with the text) in the bottom and make it's width the same as his sybilings and keep the text in the center

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I'm trying to put the second container (the one with the text) in the bottom, and i want to make the Black color Opacity the same width as the first container (image), and keep the text in the center

```
child: Stack(

             children: <Widget>
                [
           Container
           (
             padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,0,0,0),

             child: new Image
                (
                  image: new AssetImage('images/99.jpg'), 
                  fit: BoxFit.cover
                )
                ),

            new Positioned(

               bottom: 0,

               child: Container
              (
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0),

                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),


                child: Text("The text", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25.0), textAlign: TextAlign.center,), 


                ),


                  ),
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dgocv.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I think, you are searching it --**

[image]

Here is the code for this container --

```
 child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
              ),
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
                child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.black12,
                      height: 50.0,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      child: Center(child: Text("abirahsan122@gmail.com")),
                    )),
              )
            ],
          ),
```